# Map Kit On PhoneGap 1.4.0

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hello Every Developer out there...!!!!

I m currently using Phonegap 1.4.0  on iphone and i need to embed Map kit Plugin in it. but unfortunately it seems like They have removed the (Phonegap/JSON) files from the framework. i tried using 
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit and its dropping the pin but not loading the map Correctly. all it is showing is a grid.

Help me out guys. there is a deadline on me...!!!

Thanks aton

W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good tutorial: http://adventureswithcode.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/using-mapkit-plugin-for-phonegap-with-xcode-4-and-ios/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin probably needs to be updated to use the JSON framework that PhoneGap now uses (it had to change for licensing issues when it was handed over to the Apache Foundation).

I would suggest contacting the developer directly and ask if they have any plans for updating the plugin. If they do not, or it might take too long, you could always call out to the PhoneGap community on the google group and see if anyone would be interested in forking and updating the plugin if you are not able to do so yourself.

Comment: yeah i tried both... i used a new Json framework from Github. but the problem is still unsolved.